# Cannot find package openjdk-7-jre

Tags: raspbmc, java, osmc, rpi-update, rpi-source

I am trying to install JDownloader on my raspberry pi who have osmc (debian) as a OS. I am trying to install run below command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

and it says

```
Package openjdk-7-jre is a virtual package provided by:  
oracle-java9-installer 9b81+9b81arm-1~webupd8~1
oracle-java8-installer 8u60+8u60arm-1~webupd8~1
oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'openjdk-7-jre' has no installation candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which Java you have, type:

"sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer 9b81+9b81arm-1~webupd8~1"

Replace the 7 with whatever java version you have (or will download).

Comment: thank you, it is the little details that really help a new user and prevent him/her having additional problems.

Answer (score 0):

I created a script that install the current version of headless [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org) on raspberry pi running osmc kodi, and create service to start automatically (after boot and restart after crash).

**You can find entire script here:**
https://gist.github.com/atiris/34dc670264274b3a472f2a718e4de83a

Each step is asking for install so you can install only one part (for example install only Java on your raspberry pi) or all of this stuff.

You can also run this script from command line (you do not need to copy the script to the console) with command:

```bsh
SCRIPT=`curl -Ls https://gist.github.com/atiris/34dc670264274b3a472f2a718e4de83a/raw`
sudo bash -c "$SCRIPT"
```